# Specify a local image file to docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I've made local changes to a docker image and used `docker commit` to place it in the cache and then `docker image save` to create a local copy, to ensure that it doesn't get lost by an accidental overwrite. However, I cannot find syntax for specifying, in a `docker-compose.yaml` file, that I want to use the local image. Is this possible?

Comment: This isn't really the best workflow for using Docker: you now have a manually-committed image that you can't reproduce (in addition to your local hard disk failing, imagine trying to rebuild this image if the base OS has a critical security fix you _must_ take).  A better approach would be to describe your image using a `Dockerfile`, which you can check into source control, and use a Compose `build:` directive to reproduce as needed.

Comment: I didn't ask whether this was a good idea, I asked if it was possible. StackOverflow is not an appropriate place to tell people they're doing things a way you disapprove of. People don't owe you an explanation of their reasons for doing something in a way you think is wrong.

Comment: As it happens, I have reasons I'm sure you'd accept as valid. I'm not sharing them, though, because they're irrelevant. Answer questions; *don't* editorialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood the result of `docker image save`: it creates a *tarball*, not a full image. So it cannot be used directly - `docker image load`/`docker import` is needed to make it usable.

So this is not possible AFAICT. It seems unlikely that this feature is going to be developed later, either.

Answer (score 0):

In the docker-compose you can specify the image name. You can create a [tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) and use that in your docker-compose.

Comment: Tags don't do anything to guarantee the image is preserved - others might set that same tag or the cache might be cleared.

Comment: If you can create a tarball and give it a tag that docker-compose will be able to use to identify it, such that it will automatically import the tarball as an image and then use that image, that would be a different story. AFAICT that is not possible.